# Does runif() really have a range: 0<= runif(n) <= 1, as stated in the documentation?

Tags: r, random

I'm new to R, but the documentation surprised me by stating that runif(n) returns a number in the range 0 to 1 *inclusive*.
I would expect 0 <= runif(n) < 1 -- including 0 and not including 1.

I tested it with n = 100,000,000, and found that it never produced 0 or 1. I realize that the probability of actually hitting specific values in floating point is really small, but still... (There are something like 2^53 values between 0 and 1 in double precision).

So I looked into the source code for R and found in r-source-trunk\src\nmath\runif.c

```
do 
{
    u = unif_rand();
} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
return a + (b - a) * u;
```

So by design, despite the documentation, it will never ever return a 0 or 1.
Isn't this a bug?

Or at least a problem with the documentation?

Comment: You can't wait for 1 or 0, because it is a continuous distribution  .. but what you can do is evaluate the probability that u < epsilon with arbitrary small epsilon

Comment: I'm not sure what documentation you read but is doesn't appear to be the official documentation help("runif") which I just checked.

Comment: The 32-bit Mersenne twister will only produce up to `2^32` values (though its cycle size is much larger) so you aren't going to get all of those 2^53 or so representable values anyway. The documentation you read probably says what it says since in probability literature a uniform random variable is typically described as having a support like `[a,b]` rather than `(a,b)`.

Comment: WRT Documentation: see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/fullrefman.pdf, page  1659, but as Jesse Tweedle pointed out, I missed the part about it not ever returning the extremes. ( I was really looking at help in rstudio, but I don't have that in front of me at the moment)

Comment: @JohnColeman: Well, it could generate _two_ consecutive uint32 samples from the underlying 32-bit MT, and then use both to construct a double-precision float, in which case you'd expect to be able to generate many more than 2^32 distinct floats. That's what [Python does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d499031f5f33c3ef71be7c81ef52eee6b47c42e1/Modules/_randommodule.c#L140-L145). But I see from the source that R doesn't do that, which surprises me a bit.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point. I didn't look at the source, but `?RNG` is pretty clear about the built-in generators returning `2^32` (or fewer) distinct values. I suspect that R does what it does for reasons of efficiency. For some Monte Carlo applications, random number generation is the major bottleneck and using to successive values might slow down the entire algorithm by a factor of almost 2. If it is really an issue, there is a way for a user to specify a different-defined RNG. Surely there must be some package that does so with a 64-bit twister.

Comment: Anyway, the number of doubles that are between 0 and 1 is more like 2^62: the exponent ranges from -1022 to +1023, so about half of the representable numbers have modulus smaller than 1 (and half of them are positive). These values are *not* equispaced, though: they get more dense around 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underlying uniform random number function is defined [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/452e284fe7c76ee25f5cac36614f79758546c051/src/main/RNG.c) and the final outputs use this function:

```
static double fixup(double x)
{
    /* ensure 0 and 1 are never returned */
    if(x <= 0.0) return 0.5*i2_32m1;
    if((1.0 - x) <= 0.0) return 1.0 - 0.5*i2_32m1;
    return x;
}
```

Despite this, there are comments of the form `/* in [0,1) */` for each of the generator's return functions, which I assume is a mistake given the above.

And of course, the code you noticed in runif.c is preceded by:

```
/* This is true of all builtin generators, but protect against
       user-supplied ones */
```

So the min or max will never be returned except in the cases mentioned by @JesseTweedle, which is not the case when just calling `runif()`.

For reference, the magic value `i2_32m1` is `1/(2^32-1)` so the minimum value you can get from the default generators is `1/(2^33-2)` which is approximately `1.16e-10`. The maximum value is this amount short of 1.

Answer (score 6):

## The documentation says:

> runif will not generate either of the extreme values unless max = min
>   or max-min is small compared to min, and in particular not for the
>   default arguments.

With default arguments, the documentation is consistent with the behaviour you see.