# R: define range with open lower limit and closed upper limit

Tags: r, range

How to define a range in R of the following form?

(0, 5]

Does the `range()` function have an option for this?

What would be the best way to pick a random number in a range of the form `(x-1, x]` given `x`?

I have done the following so far:

x=1
round(stats::runif(length(x), x-1, x), 2))

I just want to make sure to never obtain 0 here. Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like `c(sample(1:(x-1), 1), x)`? I.e. only positive integers?

Comment: This is usually not something you have to concern yourself with. Anyway, from the documentation: "runif will not generate either of the extreme values unless max = min or max-min is small compared to min, ..." See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427049/1412059

Comment: But of course, if you round, all bets are off. You are better of using something like `round(sample(seq(from = x - 1 + 0.01, to = x, by = 0.01), n), 2)` in that case.

Comment: What is `1 round(stats::runif(length(x), x-1, x), 2))` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks @Roland! That is actually what I'm going to do just in case