# Decimal precision problems with runif

Tags: r, random, precision, uniform-distribution

I'm running into issues when simulating low-probability events with `runif` in R, and wondering how to solve this.

Consider the following example for an experiment where we simulate values of TRUE with probability 5e-10 in a sample of size 10e9, and check if any of these samples got that value of TRUE. This experiment is repeated 10 times:

```
set.seed(123)
probability <- 0.0000000005
n_samples <- 1000000000
n_tries <- 10
for (i in 1:n_tries) {
  print(any(runif(n=n_samples, min=0, max=1) < probability))
}
```

Code above will run relatively fast, and nearly half of the experiment replicates will return TRUE as expected.

However, as soon as the probability becomes 5e-11 (`probability <- 0.00000000005`), that expectation fails and no TRUE values will be returned even if the number of replicates is increased (used `n_tries <- 100` twice with no luck; the whole process took 1h running).

This means `runif` is not returning values with as many precision as 11 decimals. This was unexpected, as R to my understanding works with as much as 16 decimals of precision, and we might need to simulate processes with probabilities that small (around 15 decimals).

Is this why `runif` fails to provide the expected output?  are there any other alternatives/solutions to this problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**: I have made a test to check whether this problem could be related to boundary bias (causing a reduced density of probability near extreme values of 0 or 1). To do so, the result of `runif` is added a constant (e.g. `k <- 0.5`) and compared against the value of probability plus that same constant. However, that does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I think it is not about `runif` it can return to 30 decimals 
 try `sprintf("%.30f",runif(100)[1])`

Comment: Ok that was quite helpful actually. So it seems that the problem is in the `<` operator? the following comparison will return FALSE, while it is the same number just changing the last decimal: 0.694614463718608021736145019531 < 0.694614463718608021736145019532. **EDIT**: But it does not happen for other comparisons, e.g.  in the order of decimals I'm using. I'm not understanding this problem.

Comment: It is about ' .Machine$double.eps ' try  '0.6946144637186080 < 0.6946144637186081'

Comment: Tried with python and get the same problem see this [python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfRfg.png)

Comment: Under the default generator, `runif` appears to always produce values of the form `i / 2**32`. You can easily check this by scaling the output of `runif` by `2**32` and checking that the resulting values are integers. As a special case, it looks as though there may be a fixup for an output of `0` that produces a value around `1/2**33`, in which case `runif` will never produce values smaller than `2**-33` (around `1.1e-10`).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48428360/270986

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That helps a lot making the problem more clear.